# When loading a DEM in Google Earth Engine, it doesn't load the full map extend

Tags: google-earth-engine, dem, elevation

I want to download a digital elevation model for a major part of Europe.

Last time I tried it with the "NASA NASADEM Digital Elevation 30m", wich can be found here: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/NASA_NASADEM_HGT_001#description

**However, I encounter the problem, that the northern part of the map extend is completely cut off**, as you can see in the picture below. When I download the DEM TIF data like this, the pixels of the entire cut-off-region only contain the value "0", respectively an elevation of zero.

[image: screenshot of my GEE windor after running the code]

**Here is the code I use:**

```
// Import the dataset and select the elevation band.
var dataset = ee.Image('NASA/NASADEM_HGT/001');
var elevation = dataset.select('elevation');

// Add a white background image to the map.
var background = ee.Image(1);
Map.addLayer(background, {min: 0, max: 1});

// Set elevation visualization properties.
var elevationVis = {
  min: 0,
  max: 2000,
};

// Set elevation <= 0 as transparent and add to the map.
Map.addLayer(elevation.updateMask(elevation.gt(0)), elevationVis, 'Elevation');

Export.image.toDrive({ 
  image: elevation, 
  description: 'elevation', 
  folder: 'Digital Elevation Model Europe', 
  scale: 100, 
  region: geometry, 
  maxPixels: 5e9 // --> change the maxPixels for different resolution
})
```

Comment: This is due to the data and not due to Google Earth Engine. Try another DEM that covers the entire earth.

Comment: ah seriously?! I have tried it with an other one before, but it looks like that got the same weird map extend. Thanks for the quick answer though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @JonasV, it's the data. SRTM only covers the globe from  56°S to 60°N as shown [here](https://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/srtm/images/SRTM_2-24-2016.gif) and described [here](https://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/srtm/):

[image: srtm near-global coverage]

Comment: alright, thanks mate!